How can I add a clickable link to my LinkedIn carousel PDF post?
I've created a multi page PDF in Adobe Indesign and exported it as an Interactive PDF. It contains a clickable link. When I post it to Linkedin as a Carousel post, the link is no longer clickable. Is there any way to make clickable links within a linked carousel post so my audience can click directly on the image/PDF in the post and go to an outside link? TIA!
I've created a multi page PDF in Adobe Indesign and exported it as an Interactive PDF. It contains a clickable link. When I post it to Linkedin as a Carousel post, the link is no longer clickable.

Embedded links in carousels are no longer supported when viewed on LinkedIn or the app. That support was removed in June of 2023. However, if someone downloads the carousel (PDF) from LinkedIn and views it in a regular PDF viewer (e.g. Acrobat), then the embedded links will work as expected.
